# Handle a request with a specific function in a component

Tags: aurelia

We are developing a component that handles OpenID Connect's implicit flow.

In [step 5 of the flow](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowSteps), the "Authorization Server sends the End-User back to the Client with an ID Token and, if requested, an Access Token."  We would like our component to handle that request, which will be to `~/openid-login`.

How do we configure Aurelia to have it route to a function in our component?

```
export class OpenId {

    // how do we route ~/openid-login to this?
    public handleRequest() {

    }

}
```

Note: [Here is the work in progress.](https://github.com/shaunluttin/openiddict-samples/tree/spa-sample/samples/ImplicitFlow/AureliaApp/src)

Answer (score 2):

Using a navStrategy within your routeConfig will allow you to do what ever you like before navigating to a page. See below:

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { RouterConfiguration, Router, NavigationInstruction } from 'aurelia-router';

@autoinject
export class App {

    router: Router;

    configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {

        let openIdNavStrat = (instruction: NavigationInstruction) => {

            console.log('Do whatever we would like to do.');

            // then redirect to where ever you would like.
            instruction.config.moduleId = 'login';
        }

        config.map([
            { route: ['', 'login'], moduleId: 'login' },
            { route: 'openid-login', navigationStrategy: openIdNavStrat },
        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

There is documentation on Navigation Strategies here: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/3

Comment: Will this also require that we have an app.html view that has a router-view in it?